# On the matrix representation of a composition of Möbius transforms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition, mobius-transformation

Let the *Möbius transform associated to the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$* be defined as $\mu_A:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C:z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ provided $\det A\neq 0$.
It is straightforward to verify that $\mu_A\circ\mu_B=\mu_{AB}$. I was wondering if there is a more intuitive (and preferably elementary) way to see why we have this identity without having to do the calculation.

I was thinking of viewing $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ as a 'formal' fraction; that is, just another notation for $\begin{pmatrix}az+b\\cz+d\end{pmatrix}$ and then trying to find out if $AB\begin{pmatrix}z\\1\end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to the usual composition $\mu_A\circ\mu_B$. I can't see it. There should be a deeper reason for this.

Comment: What is the "algebra-precalculus" tag doing here?

Comment: The description says "... and other symbolic-manipulation topics." That's why. I must say I hesitated about adding this tag, but it seemed more appropriate than [tag:matrices] or [tag:abstract-algebra]. Retag if you feel the need to.

Comment: It has to do with homogeneous coordinates in projective space. Section 3.VI in Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group action of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb C)$ on $\mathbb C^2$ by left multiplication:

- stabilizes $(0,0)$, so it restricts to $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$
- is linear, so descends to the projective space $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C) = (\mathbb C^2\setminus 0)/\mathbb C^\times$

In $\mathbb P^1$, $[x, y] = [\frac xy,1]$ for $y\neq0$, so in the first coordinate map the group action reads $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
for $z\neq\infty$ and $cz+d \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a quite nice section about the [(projective) matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations) of the Möbius transformation. The key insight is to realize that $z$ can be represented as a vector with [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), $\vec{z}$, and that this basically turns the Möbius transformation into a matrix multiplication in linear algebra, and those multiplications are associative.

So, a chained Möbius transformation $\mu_A\circ(\mu_B\circ z)$ can be written as $A(B\,\vec{z})$ if we represent the Möbius transforations $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ as the two-by-two matrices $A$ and $B$, respectively, and $z$ as a vector with homogenuous coordinates, $\vec{z}$. Since matrix multiplications are associative, we can rewrite $A(B\,\vec{z})$ as $(AB)\vec{z}$, which is just another way to represent the Möbius transformation $\mu_{AB}\circ z$.